# Mysql -query : How to find task assiged to which developer

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a85c/1)
One task can be re assigned to another developer. I want to find task which are reassigned to particular developer.

For example Task one was assigned to user 1 then user 2 then user 3.
If user 3 is logged he could see task one in list of reassigned tasks.

following is the schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `task` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

Query

```
SELECT count(*) as num, a.user_id, max(a.id)
FROM task a
group by a.task_id
having num > 1
```

Please help me to find list of task of user 3 those was with other and now with user 3.

Comment: Your query and your question are inconsistent.  Are you trying to find the most recent task for a single user or for all users?

Comment: @dnoeth, > 1, not >= 1.

Comment: i want to find for a user. not for all. I am just trying and stuck where to add user_id condition in this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
from task as t1
where user_id = 3                    -- particular developer
and exists 
    (select *
     from task as t2
     where t2.task_id = t1.task_id   -- same task
       and t2.created < t1.created   -- previously assigned
       and t2.user_id <> t1.user_id  -- to a different user
    )
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81452f/2)

Comment: thank for your reply. It gives only one record in result. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81452f/1   this should give two records in result

Comment: @pandudas: there's a task assigned to both user *2* and *3* at the same time. If this is actually possible then chaange the condition to `and t2.created <= t1.created`, modified http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/81452f/2